# Javascript - I created a form with multiple values, but only one is calculating?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculated-columns

I'm not sure why, but only oranges seems to calculate in the form I created, but the other fruits I specified don't.  I have the each .value specified for each fruit.  The form for all fruits are logically identical from what I can see, so I don't understand why I'm not getting result from watermelon or pineapple.

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
```

```
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 

<title> Purchase Orange </title>
    <!-- Script for the event handlers --> 

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            // The event handler function to compute the cost

            function computeCost() {
                var orange = document.getElementById("orange").value;
                // Compute the cost
                document.getElementById("cost").value = orange * 1.99;


                var watermelon = document.getElementById("Watermelon").value;
                document.getElementById("cost").value = watermelon * 4.99;

                var pineapple = document.getElementById("Pineapple").value;
                document.getElementById("cost").value = pineapple * 4.69;



            } //* end of computeCost 
        </script>

</head> 

<body> 

<form>
    Orange $1.99/lb <input type = "text" id = "orange" size ="3" />
    <br />

</form> 

<form>
    Watermelon $4.99/lb <input type = "text" id = "watermelon" size ="3" />
    <br />

</form> 

<form>
    Pineapple $4.69/lb <input type = "text" id = "pineapple" size ="3" />
    <br />
</form>

<form>      
    Total Cost is <input type = "text" id = "cost" size ="5" />
    <br />
</form>

<form>      
    <input type = "button" value = "Total Cost" onclick="computeCost();"/>
</form> 

</body>
```

Comment: Do you want to get sub total?

Comment: I want to get total for each fruit in the field.  So far, the only total that calulates is orange, but not the other fruits.   There are fields for each fruit when you run the code, each field has a box where you can input the quantity.  Orange calculates with the 1.99 price I specified, and the calculation goes into the total field I created.  But it doesn't do that for Pineapple and Watermelon.

Comment: you have to sumup all your variables after making id correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a simple/capital issue in your IDs, did a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrgv755g/), check this out.

```
       function computeCost() {
            var orange = document.getElementById("orange").value;
            // Compute the cost
            var a = orange * 1.99;


            var watermelon = document.getElementById("watermelon").value;
            var b = watermelon * 4.99;

            var pineapple = document.getElementById("pineapple").value;
            var c = pineapple * 4.69;

            var total = eval(a + b + c);

            document.getElementById("cost").value = total;                


        } //* end of computeCost
```

Comment: Ah Thanks!  I see what I did wrong.  putting a, b and c and assigning it to each fruit makes it easier.  And then eval (a+b+c) helps with the total.  Thanks :)  I wish I could give upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you are using wrong Id's:

use:

```
var watermelon = document.getElementById("watermelon").value;
 var pineapple = document.getElementById("pineapple").value;
```

instead of:

```
     var watermelon = document.getElementById("Watermelon").value;
        var pineapple = document.getElementById("Pineapple").value;
```

display sum of all the calculated values.like this:

```
var grandtotal =pineapple+ watermelon+orange;
        document.getElementById("cost").value = grandtotal;
```

Comment: Just tried that.  Now nothing calculates.  I can't figure out what's wrong.   I'll edit my post above, is it the script that's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

change the case of your id

```
var watermelon = document.getElementById("watermelon").value;

var pineapple = document.getElementById("pineapple").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is because getDocumentById is Key sensitive. You have wrote your Id like 
this : `pineapple` and `watermelon` and you check for them with a capital letter like this : `Pineapple` and `Watermelon`.